# Does any specific property decide which DNA strand acts as leading strand template?

Tags: molecular-genetics, dna-replication

Of the two strands of DNA, the one that unwinds in the 3' to 5' direction constitutes the leading strand template, with the other strand of course acting as the lagging strand template. Is there any specific property - such as a specific base pair sequence present on one of the strands - which decides that **that** strand shall be the leading strand template - whereas the second strand with the complimentary sequence will be the lagging strand template? What decides, in other words, which of the two strands will be unwound in the 3' to 5' direction (effectively rendering it the leading strand template and the second strand the lagging strand template)?

Comment: Basically, the orientation of the origin of replication sequence decides that. I'll read up a bit on that and give you a full answer.